# How to get field of new instance from one class to another

Tags: c#, object

So I am implementing a rudimentary Hotel booking system with a check in and check out method. For the check in and check out selections, I have a switch statement that allows the user to pick a room by selecting a number. I have a truncated version of the code below, as the case statement pretty much are similar in nature:

```
case 1:
        if (true)//this is supposed to check if the room is booked
        {
             Console.WriteLine("This room is already booked, please try another place");
         }
        else
        {
           var instance1 = new BookingMethods();
           instance1.bookRoom1();
           revenueGenerated += 100; 
         }
        break;
```

For the if statements, I'm trying to check if the rooms are booked or not, and I have created objects in another class along the methods for checking in and out. Below is how I did this:

```
class BookingMethods
{
    Room room1 = new Room();

    public void bookRoom1()
    {
        //code for generating ints
        room1.occupied = true;
        room1.numGuests = guests1;
        room1.daysBooked = staying1;
        room1.roomType = "luxury";
    }
}
```

I want the if statement to be able to read `room1.occupied` for the condition, but I can't seem to be able to reference it correctly. I have `bookRoom1()` in my `BookingMethods.cs` from the case statement, which is in my `Program.cs`. I figured I don't have to move my `Room` object from `BookingMethods.cs` to `Program.cs` to do this, and I haven't been able to figure out a way to call it.

Comment: I think you must create a Room object in the class which contains switch  condition. Also bookRoom() method's parameter must be a Room parameter. That is bookRoom(Room r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify an access modifier for `room1`. If you do not provide one, it is set to `private` by default, meaning it is only accessible in the class in which it is declared. In addition to this, you should really create a property.

This should get you going:

```
var instance1 = new BookingMethods();
switch (instance1.room1.occupied)
{
    case true:
         Console.WriteLine("This room is already booked, please try another place");
    break;
    default:
        instance1.bookRoom1();
        revenueGenerated += 100; 
    break;
}

class BookingMethods
{
    public Room room1 {get; set;};

    public void bookRoom1()
    {
        //code for generating ints
        room1.occupied = true;
        room1.numGuests = guests1;
        room1.daysBooked = staying1;
        room1.roomType = "luxury";
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I thought public was the default access modifier. Makes sense now.

Comment: Also probably worth mentioning that the way you have things set up is going to cause you a lot of headache in the long run. Consider removing the instantiation of the `Room` object out of your `BookingMethods` class. Have your `BookRoom` method take all parameters needed for the booking process. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make room1 a field

```
class BookingMethods
{
    Room room1 {get; set;};

    public void bookRoom1()
    {
        //code for generating ints
        room1.occupied = true;
        room1.numGuests = guests1;
        room1.daysBooked = staying1;
        room1.roomType = "luxury";
    }
}
```

Comment: `room1` is still private in this case and not accessible from outside of `BookingMethods`.